# Groovy replaceAll replacing multiple half matched strings

Tags: groovy, replaceall

Working on a script where a user provides a file (yaml/json/txt) which has some string-formats to be replaced.These string formats can occur at any index.

The problem I'm facing is that replaceAll is replacing multiple half-matched strings. Example:

```
def secretfile = "This is first secret.adminlogin and then comes secret.adminloginpassword";
println(secretfile.replaceAll("secret.adminlogin", "root"));
```

This is resulting in "This is first root and then comes rootpassword" .
Where as the expected result is "This is first root and then comes secret.adminloginpassword"

How can we make groovy replaceAll to only look for exact match of string.

P.S , I cannot use split + replace + concatenation as the file can be a yaml/json and it might break it's linting.

Comment: Surround your regex pattern with `\b`. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html.

Comment: @jaco0646 Thank you, that works println(secretfile.replaceAll(/\bsecret.adminlogin\b/, "root"));

Comment: you should also escape the `.`